# Write permission problems

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a problem with my website files.
I have set the permissions of files to :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   40 oct.  20 09:58 session.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   63 oct.  20 09:58 log.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  525 oct.  20 09:58 locale.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  386 oct.  20 09:58 database.json.example
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data 4,0K oct.  20 10:01 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  386 oct.  20 10:09 database.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4,0K oct.  20 10:10 .
```

And I have put my acount to the www-data group :

```
$ groups Valentin
Valentin : Valentin www-data
```

But when i try to create a new file or if i try to save an existing file i have an "Permission Denied" error.

What have i done wrong ?

EDIT : After few other trys, it apears that I have the "other" permission. But i don't understand why... I am in fact in the "www-data" group so i should have the "group" permissions no ?

Comment: Did you try to create the file with root privileges?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't solved the problem. I want to be able to modify files without a sudo command...

Comment: Switch user in terminal and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That you are a member of the group `www-data` does not mean that you have access to files of the group `www-data` without further ado. For determining the access right, the current group ID is drawn on. You can view the group ID (gid) with the command

```
id
```

and change it e. g. with

```
newgrp www-data
```

to exercise your access rights for that group.